# How do I select the image column in rails when using where & select clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, paperclip

I have been using paperclip to upload and fetch image(s) url. My question is how do I select the logo column? 
for eg: User table structure
`id` ,`name`, `logo_file_name`, `logo_content_type` **+ more columns**
when I do `u = User.find(1).logo` getting the result which is great. Now when I'm doing `u = User.select('name', 'logo').where('something')` receiving error saying there is no such column as **u.logo** which is clear to me, since there is no column that's why it's giving me error, but how do fetch image url in later condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this question by myself here is a quick answer to it, need to select all 4 columns which are generated by paperclip for example i.e. `users.logo_file_name, users.logo_content_type, users.logo_file_size, users.logo_updated_at`

So when we do

`u = User.select('logo_file_name, logo_content_type, logo_file_size, logo_updated_at').where(id: 29)` and then doing
`u.first.logo`  Getting the image URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include logo columns ActiveRecord won't be able to serialise that.

So if you want instances of User to respond to logo then just include that in your select statement.

Comment: I did that `u = User.select('name', 'logo').where('something')`

Comment: @VibhooMishra try including other fields related to logos, maybe content type etc... I guess paperclip is Having problems when serialising data since some fields are missing.

Comment: did that also `u = User.select('name,logo_file_name, logo_content_type').where('something')` still same.